# Python 2.8 - deleting .001, .002, etc

Tags: python

I found several threads on this subject but could not distill a solution.  I am trying to delete .001, .002, etc.

The code should delete these, but every time I rerun my code it is as if nothing was ever deleted; the count is now >0.250 and is rising rapidly.

Full disclosure:  The solution below is inefficient; it is the culmination of several efforts to solve my problem and represents my final "brute force" approach.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions:

````
def delete_object_iteration(objname):
    for x in range(1, 999):
        xs=str(x)
        on2=objname+'.'+xs.zfill(3)
        try:
            bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.context.scene.objects[on2], do_unlink = True)
        except:
            pass
        delete_object_instance(on2)

def delete_object_instance(objname):  
    try:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.data.objects[objname].select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
    except:
        pass
```
````

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you call `delete_object_instance` after you've already removed the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script works fast and removes the objects.

```
import bpy


def delete_object_iteration(obj_name):
    for x in range(1, 999):
        obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(obj_name + '.' + str(x).zfill(3))
        if obj is not None:
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True) 

delete_object_iteration("Cube")
```

The alternative approach would be using the operator with context override.

```
import bpy


def delete_object_iteration(obj_name):
    objs = []
    for x in range(1, 999):
        obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(obj_name + '.' + str(x).zfill(3))
        if obj is not None:
            objs.append(obj)
    bpy.ops.object.delete({"selected_objects": objs})

delete_object_iteration("Cube")
```

In case you don't want to remove only between 1 and 999:

```
import bpy

def is_match(prefix, name):
    split_name = name.split('.')      
    if len(split_name) == 2 and split_name[0] == prefix and split_name[1].isdigit():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def delete_object_iteration(obj_name):
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        if is_match(obj_name, obj.name):
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True) 

delete_object_iteration("Cube")
```

Purging orphans as well:

```
import bpy

def is_match(prefix, name):
    split_name = name.split('.')     
    if len(split_name) == 2 and split_name[0] == prefix and split_name[1].isdigit():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def purge_orphans():
    old_type = bpy.context.area.type
    bpy.context.area.type = 'OUTLINER'
    bpy.context.space_data.display_mode = 'ORPHAN_DATA'
    bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge()
    bpy.context.area.type = old_type

def delete_object_iteration(obj_name):
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        if is_match(obj_name, obj.name):
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)
    purge_orphans()

delete_object_iteration("Cube")
```

Comment: Oops... posted without noticing you  had edited answer to include similar.

Comment: @batFINGER no problem. You're answer also includes variations that mine doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

**Finding with `re`**

Alternatively, find all objects that match a pattern using active objects name.  With object "Cube" active a simple `re` could be

```
regexp = r'Cube.\d+'
```

any object with a name starting with "Cube." and ending only with digits past that point will match.  Need only iterate over `scene.objects`, or any collection containing objects eg all in blend  `bpy.data.objects`, and see if they match, as opposed to finding if any of each of a  1000 exist.

*There are other ways without `re`, eg `split` or `rpartition` on "." and test if part is numeric.*

```
>>> "Cube.001".rpartition(".")
('Cube', '.', '001')
```

Test script finds the matches.

```
import bpy
import re

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
ob = context.object

rexp = f"{ob.name}.\d+"

matches = [o for o in scene.objects if re.fullmatch(rexp, o.name)]

print(matches)
```

Ok if we have matches, can iterate and delete from blend.

```
while matches:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(matches.pop())
```

Or with the operator, passing a context override.

```
if matches:
    bpy.ops.object.delete({"selected_objects" : matches})
```

There is a lot of over zealous hoo-ha re not using operators.  If you had 1000s of matches above, the operator is still called only once... IMO this is Ok.

but **Don't!!!!** do this

```
for o in matches:
    bpy.ops.some.op(....)
```

and call the operator 1000s of times.

[Python performance with Blender operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators/7360)

[Why avoid bpy.ops?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops)

Please also note that `bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(...)` has similar functionality, and this could be a 2 liner.

```
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Cube.*", extend=False)
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

*Which will delete "Cube.001.001" also.*

Comment: Sorry to intrude .. but this is the sort of place I'm getting stuck trying to figure out  the API. The only ref. I have to `bpy.ops.object.delete` is [this one](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=bpy%20ops%20delete#bpy.ops.object.delete) .. I assume you're replacing a `context` parameter with a dictionary of your own ... where would I find the docs for that? Is `context` an default parameter for all ops calls, or something?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35653/reliable-way-to-find-out-the-required-context-for-an-operator  Would _love_ to see the required context members in the docs.

Comment: Thanks. It's nice to know I'm not he only one. With the occasional help of folks like you, I'll muddle through.. :)